# Is it possible to import a Maven JAR in a regular Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is it possible to import a Maven JAR in a regular Java project? 
If yes how to do so. I am using Eclipse Neon IDE.

Comment: What does regular mean to you?  Is it a Maven project or is it not?

Comment: A jar can always be added to any java project. Maven is just a means of getting the jar there.

Comment: @duffymo It is not a maven project. But the jar is.

Comment: What JAR?  Does a Maven JAR mean that it is managed by Maven, or part of the Maven distro?

Comment: just add its dependency in the application's classpath, generally in \.m2\repository\com\your_dependency.jar

Comment: You should be able to add it like any other jar file into your dependencies

Comment: @duffymo This is the Jar I want to import Java-frontend-4.7.1.9272. I am new to it so I dont know if is a maven distro.

Comment: .m2 won't come into play if you're not using Maven.  Before I used Maven I would create a /lib folder for all 3rd party JARs and add them manually to my project.  I'd tell my IDE that the contents in the /lib folder were all part of the CLASSPATH.  That name suggests that it's a JAR created internally in your shop.

Comment: @dilnei I'll try it. Thank you

Comment: nbokmans and bill F thank you. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is absolutely possible to import local maven repository's jar in your  simple java project in eclipse.
Since maven download jars in local repository which is on your computer (in general)   .So you can use those jars as you normally use downloaded jars from other location in your computer.
To know maven repository location from eclipse
Click on window->preference ->type maven in search->user setting -> you will **Local Repository**
as shown in below snap shot[image]

Comment: Thank you but I did not understand it. I want to use the maven jars in my simple project. But want to keep the project as simple java project and don't want to change it into a maven project. All the required jar files are on the desktop. How should I use them in my project.